# django, combine two group by query

Tags: sql, django, django-queryset

I have the following models

```
class Accept(models.Model):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    invitation = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


class OfferBase(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    accepts = generic.GenericRelation(Accept)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class FooOffer(OfferBase):

    # pass


class BarOffer(OfferBase):

    # pass
```

I'd like to count # of accepts grouped by user ordered by # accepts

In django,

```
FooOffer.object.values('user', 'user__username'
).annotate(num_accepts=Count('accepts__id')).order_by('-num_accepts')
```

In sql,

```
SELECT "foo_offer"."user_id", "user"."username", COUNT("accept"."id") AS "num_accepts" FROM "foo_offer" INNER JOIN "user" ON ( "foo_offer"."user_id" = "user"."id" ) LEFT OUTER JOIN "accept" ON ( "foo_offer"."id" = "accept"."object_id" AND ("accept"."content_type_id" = 20\
2) ) GROUP BY "foo_offer"."user_id", "user"."username" ORDER BY "num_accepts" DESC


BarOffer.object.values('user', 'user__username'
).annotate(num_accepts=Count('accepts__id')).order_by('-num_accepts')
```

I'd like to combine the result of the two query (Foo and Bar)
I don't know how to write that in sql, I guess I need `union` and `sum`
How do I do that in django?
Maybe it might not be possible to do this with ORM, then how do I do the query without orm in django world?

the resulting rows would have the following columns.

```
user_id         username                sum( count(accept.id) )
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about this but I don't think you could combine them, because they are querysets on 2 different models. Even if you made them inherit from one model, but that model is abstract, which doesn't support query.

Comment: could you show the struct of table foo_offer,table user and table accept?In my opinion you can do the count first for accept as a sub query then join 3 table together but it maybe not you want, we need more information of the problem.

Comment: I've included FooOffer, Accept model definition in the op. User is just a model with `username` for simplicity